# C# Returning Plain Json from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send data as plain Json, from my controller to the client side of my MVC application. The data is initially collected as a list of objects but I'm having trouble converting it to straight Json. Right now the code in my controller is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult SecurityPermissionsTableData()
{
    List<SecurityPermissionsGridModel> list = securityPermissionsTable.Get(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\').Last());

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        data = list
    });

    return ResultJson(json);
}

public JsonResult ResultJson(object data)
{
    return new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, Data = data };
}
```

When I use the JsonConvert.SerializeObject() function, it returns a string:

```
"{\"data\":[{\"Username\":\"loganfg\",\"readbutton\":null,\"editbutton\":null,\"deletebutton\":null}]}"
```

However I need to return plain Json in the form of:

```
{"data":[{"Username":"lgilmore","readbutton":"<a onclick='SP_read(\"7\")' class='SRKbutton tiny SP_rbutton'>Details</a>","editbutton":null,"deletebutton":null}]}
```

How can I convert the string the serialize function returns to plain Json? Or how do I alter my ResultJson() function to properly handle and convert the string?

Answer (score 5):

`JsonResult` already serializes the object for you.
Therefore, it's serializing your *string* to a JSON string literal.

You should get rid of all of your code and just

```
return Json(list, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may simply use the `Json` method.

Pass the object you want to convert to json as the parameter.

```
public JsonResult SecurityPermissionsTableData()
{
   var permissionList = securityPermissionsTable
                .Get(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
                .Name.Split('\\').Last());
   return Json(permissionList , JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Json take an object, not a list of objects? And my code is:

List<SecurityPermissionsGridModel> list

not

var list

Comment: I should've been more clear, I need it in the format of a Json array, not a Json object

Comment: @Life761 It will return an array if `securityPermissionsTable.Get` method returns a collection. If you pass a single object, It will return json for a single structure. If you pass an array, it will return an array.